# Oxygen Builder - Wordpress: Filter post type by true/false custom field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, builder

I'm trying to filter my custom type from boolean field (true/false) but I don't know how to do.

[image]

With this meta_query the filter return 0 items. How can I filter by boolean field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I work with oxygen builder too.
what is the dynamic code for the "key"? you can copy&paste it outside the image, and it describes the question more clearly.
add compare option to the array, this may help.
[here is the example from this page][1] for your information, I think it helps to understand meta_query
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvzZT.png

https://andriy.space/wordpress-meta-query/

Comment: The value of this key is: [oxygen data="custom_acf_content" settings_path="isanalysis" settings_page="false"]

Comment: maybe you can add one more line to the array:
**compare, =**
and below is a good desc page for meta_query:
[https://andriy.space/wordpress-meta-query/](https://andriy.space/wordpress-meta-query/)

Comment: I try with this and doesnt work:

https://imgur.com/ioNDvzn

Comment: With rest api i try to filter and it doesnt work: https://camaselasticas.store/wp-json/wp/v2/camas-elasticas?meta_key=isanalysis&meta_value=true

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).